# Attaching to a remote process for debugging

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, gdb, xcode3.1

Using Xcode 3.1 on OSX 10.5; is it possible to attach (the debugger) to a running remote process?

I know that it's possible to start and debug a remote process (as explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/800-Debugging_Programs_Remotely/chapter_11_section_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057-CH11-SW1)), but it would be great if I could find a way to attach to an already running remote process...

edit to add: Thanks. I've submitted a bug report to Apple. Will update this question if/when I hear back from them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no nice gui for it in XCode but you can do it this way:

1. start a second instance of the program from XCode with remote debugging,
2. use the GDB attach command from the console

Step by step instructions:

1. Follow Apple's [instructions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/300-Debugging_Programs_Remotely/remote_debugging.html) to set up remote debuging:
2. Find out the *process-id* of the running instance of your program on the remote box:

   ssh "remotemachine" 'ps -x -w -w' | grep "AppName"

   (you can also use ARD and ActivityMonitor)
3. Put a breakpoint to your app main, and start a second instance from the Debugger (on the remote box)
4. In the GDB console (Run/Console menu) enter:

   attach *process-id*
5. Now you have you XCode attached to the running process. You can now use the graphical debugger.

(In early XCode, there was no GUI for attaching to local processes, so [this trick/hack was the solution...](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/300-Debugging_Programs_Remotely/remote_debugging.html))

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/300-Debugging_Programs_Remotely/remote_debugging.html

Comment: Looks like the developer.apple.com links are no longer working. Does anyone know where these are actually supposed to go?